# Почему я получаю ошибку Assignment to constant variable, хотя переменная была создана через let

Tags: javascript, массивы

Ошибка: createInteractionPanel.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
at deleteNote (createInteractionPanel.js:11:21)
at HTMLImageElement. (createInteractionPanel.js:26:9)

Основной код:

```js
import {activeNotesData} from "../../data/activeNotesData.js";

function findParentId(el) {
    return el.parentNode.id
}

function deleteNote(id) {
    activeNotesData = activeNotesData.filter(note => note.id !== id)
}

export const createInteractionPanel = (itemId) => {

    let interactionPanel = document.createElement("div");
    interactionPanel.setAttribute("id", itemId)


    let deleteIcon = document.createElement("img");
    deleteIcon.src = "images/garbageIcon.svg";
    deleteIcon.className = "note-interaction-icon";

    deleteIcon.addEventListener('click', function () {
        deleteNote(findParentId(this))
    });

    interactionPanel.appendChild(deleteIcon);

    return interactionPanel;
}
```

Создание объекта:

```js
export let activeNotesData = [
    {
        id: 123,
        name: 'Shopping list',
        created: 'April 20, 2021',
        category: 'Quote',
        content: 'Tomatoes, bread',
        dates: ''
    },
    {
        id: Math.random() + Math.random(),
        name: 'The theory of evolution',
        created: 'April 27, 2021',
        category: 'Thought',
        content: 'The evolution The evolution The evolution',
        dates: ''
    },
    {
        id: Math.random() + Math.random(),
        name: 'New Feature',
        created: 'May 5, 2021',
        category: 'Idea',
        content: 'Implement new tomatoes, bread',
        dates: ['3/5/2021', '5/5/2021']
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

В js нельзя напрямую изменять импортируемые переменные вне зависимости от способа их объявления (const или let). Однако, эти переменные можно изменять в самом модуле, который их экспортирует.

[Подробное объяснение на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558929/15786229)

В данном случае, чтобы изменить `activeNotesData`, необходимо перенести функцию `deleteNote` из `createInteractionPanel.js` в `activeNotesData.js` (не забудьте добавить export), после чего импортировать её в `createInteractionPanel.js` вместе с `activeNotesData`.

P.S. Также, при фильтрации `activeNotesData` не забудьте привести `note.id` и `id` к одному типу, чтобы строгое неравенство `note.id !== id` работало как ожидается.
Я так понимаю, `note.id` у вас типа Number, а `id`, полученный с помощью функции `findParentId`, передается в функцию `deleteNote` с типом String.